# How to enable scrolling on disabled listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I need to disable listView in Android but still let it scroll. When I call listView.setEnabled("false"), it doesn't let me scroll it. When I call listView.setEnabled("true"), my listView receives touches and selects/deselect its items. Do you have any idea how to solve this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out. I had to override a method when setting the adapter of the list view:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(myContext, myResource, myData) {
   @Override
   public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
      return false;
  }
});
```